# Can ViewerSupport.bind() be used in conjunction with images?

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-databinding

In my Eclipse RCP View, I use JFace databinding to bind model data to a `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer`. I use `ViewerSupport.bind()` to bind the data as shown in the snippets, and it works just fine.

```
ViewerSupport.bind(viewer, model, BeanProperties.list("children",
          ModelObject.class), BeanProperties.value(ModelObject.class, "name"));
```

Now I'd really like to display an image along with the text on the nodes. Without databinding, I'd just override a `LabelProvider`'s `getImage(Object element)` method, but the content + label provider method and the use of `ViewerSupport` don't work together. I haven't found a solution to my problem in the `ViewerSupport` API. Is there a solution, perhaps using `org.eclipse.core.databinding.property.value.IValueProperty`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewerSupport` uses `ObservableMapLabelProvider` as the label provider. Unfortunately the `getImage` method for this just returns `null`.

You could perhaps uses a sub-class of `ObservableMapLabelProvider` to provide the images. You can't use `ViewerSupport` to do that so you would have to duplicate some of the code.

This is how `ViewerSupport.bind` sets up the tree:

```java
public static void bind(AbstractTreeViewer viewer, Object input,
        IListProperty childrenProperty, IValueProperty[] labelProperties) {
  Realm realm = DisplayRealm.getRealm(viewer.getControl().getDisplay());

  ObservableListTreeContentProvider contentProvider = new ObservableListTreeContentProvider(
            childrenProperty.listFactory(realm), null);

  if (viewer.getInput() != null)
    viewer.setInput(null);

  viewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);

  viewer.setLabelProvider(new ObservableMapLabelProvider(Properties
            .observeEach(contentProvider.getKnownElements(),
                    labelProperties)));

  if (input != null)
    viewer.setInput(input);
}
```

Comment: Should've thought of that myself really, thanks. Lack of an OOP mind. Shame that these methods are `static`, would've made extending so much easier.